# Top-Level tree view item not expanding when IsExpanded property updated

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a tree view showing reports/folders and is bound to my SelectedItem in the ViewModel. When SelectedItem is set programmatically I want to expand all the parent items so that SelectedItem is visible in tree view, but I cannot seem to open the top-level item specifically. My code works for expanding 2nd or 3rd level folders, but not the top level item. For example if I set MyReport/Sales/SummaryReports/Sales Report as the selected item, everything expands except for the MyReport folder.

When SelectedItem is set, code calls recursive function `SetIsExpandedToTrue(_selectedItem)`. Using the debugger, I was able to see that it ***does*** set `IsExpanded = true` for the top level MyReports folder as well, however only the lower-level folders are visually expanded in the tree view.

```
private void SetIsExpandedToTrue(ReportItem item)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.IsExpanded = true;
                if (item.Parent != null)
                {
                    SetIsExpandedToTrue(item.Parent);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have IsExpanded bound to my treeview with these two templates:

```
        <!--TreeView Folder Template-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!--TreeView File Template-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontStyle="Italic">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SSRS_Subscriptions}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And here is my actual tree view (user control, added ability to bind to SelectedItem)

```
<userControls:ExtendedTreeView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="myTreeView"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding ReportItems}" 
                                       SelectedItem_="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                       ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}"/>
```

This is the ReportItem model the tree view is using (Type = 1 is a folder, type = 2 is a report)

```
 public class ReportItem : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public ReportItem Parent { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ReportItem> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ReportItem>();
        private bool _isExpanded { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded;}
            set
            {
                if (_isExpanded != value)
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try put `IsExpanded` functionality to the implicit style for `TreeViewItem` by TreeView and remove it from `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<userControls:ExtendedTreeView x:Name="myTreeView" ..... >

   <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.Resources>

</userControls:ExtendedTreeView>
```

Comment: You're a hero. I wasted most of my day today on this.